# Check if an image URL is transparent with PHP

Tags: php

I'm looking to check a iamge URL like https://something.com/my/render_thumb.php?size=small for if it seems to be transparent, because if it's partly transparent then I will consider that it is fully transparent and then use a different image in my code. I tried to create a function that reads a url like so but it complains about the $url being of type string or something.  Any ideas on how I can quickly check image urls ?

```
// --pseudo php code (doesn't work) --
function check_transparent($url) {

    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $raw = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    $img = ImageCreateFromJpeg($raw);
    // We run the image pixel by pixel and as soon as we find a transparent pixel we stop and return true.
    for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
        for($j = 0; $j < 10; $j++) {
            $rgba = imagecolorat($img, $i, $j);
            if(($rgba & 0x7F000000) >> 24) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    // If we dont find any pixel the function will return false.
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is related to how you use `ImageCreateFromJpeg` function.

[Check out PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/it/function.imagecreatefromjpeg.php) and you'll notice that function expects a valid JPEG path or URL, and not it's raw value. So this should be the first line in your function:

```
$img = ImageCreateFromJpeg($url);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, so probably something like this might do the trick .... will give it a shot ... .

```
function getImageType($image_path) {
$typeString = '';
$typeInt = exif_imagetype($image_path);
switch ($typeInt) {
    case IMAGETYPE_GIF:
    case IMG_GIF:
        $typeString = 'image/gif';
        break;
    case IMG_JPG:
    case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
    case IMG_JPEG:
        $typeString = 'image/jpg';
        break;
    case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    case IMG_PNG:
        $typeString = 'image/png';
        break;
    default:
        $typeString = 'other ('.$typeInt.')';
}
return $typeString;
}


function check_transparent($url) {

$imgType = '';
$imgType = getImageType($url);

if ($imgType == 'image/jpg') {
    $img = ImageCreateFromJpeg($url);
} else if ($imgType == 'image/png') {
    $img = ImageCreateFromPng($url);
} else {
    return false;
}

// We run the image pixel by pixel and as soon as we find a transparent pixel we stop and return true.
for($i = 0; $i < 200; $i++) {
    for($j = 0; $j < 200; $j++) {
        $rgba = imagecolorat($img, $i, $j);
        if(($rgba & 0x7F000000) >> 24) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

// If we dont find any pixel the function will return false.
return false;
}
```

Example:

```
$url = "https://example.com/images/thumb_maker.php?size=200x200";

echo check_transparent($url);
```